# Renewing Latin Phrases in chemmacros does not work

Tags: chemmacros

I am trying to redefine a Latin phrase from the `chemmacros` package.
When I try to use `\RenewChemLatin{\insitu}{in-situ}`, the log prints

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! chemmacros error: "renew-Latin"
! 
! You've tried to renew the Latin \insitu , but it doesn't exist.
! 
! See the chemmacros documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................
```

When I try to `\ProvideChemLatin{\insitu}{in-situ}` it tells me:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! chemmacros error: "new-Latin"
! 
! You've tried to define a Latin with \NewChemLatin, but the command sequence
! \insitu  already exists. Please choose another name.
! 
! See the chemmacros documentation for further information.
! 
! Type <return> to continue.
!...............................................
```

Interestingly I get the same errors when I use `\NewDocumentCommand{\insitu}{}{\emph{in-situ}}` or `\RenewDocumentCommand{\insitu}{}{\emph{in-situ}}` repectively.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\RenewChemLatin{\insitu}{in-situ}
%\ProvideChemLatin{\insitu}{in-situ}
\begin{document}
    \insitu
\end{document}
```

So what am I missing?

Comment: Please, don't use the `minimal` class, see [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114)

Comment: Alright. I will refrain from using it in the future. I was under the impression, it was adequate for testing purposes, (as said in the answer to your link).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chemmacros` only issues

```
\NewChemLatin \insitu   { in~situ }
```

in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook (see [chemmacros.module.nomenclature.code.tex](https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/blob/725c7d93626d846313bb71e9ec9ff0a3b271fea2/chemmacros.module.nomenclature.code.tex#L818), ll. 818-835). That means that `\insitu` is not defined when `chemmacros` is loaded, it is defined only at the start of the document.

So when you say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\RenewChemLatin\insitu{in-situ}
\begin{document}
  \insitu
\end{document}
```

you get an error that you are redefining something that is undefined. And when you use `\ProvideChemLatin{\insitu}{in-situ}` instead *your* definition is fine, but the one issued by `chemmacros` in `\AtBeginDocument` throws an error, since the command is already defined.

So if you want to redefine `\insitu` you can use `\AtBeginDocument` as well. If your call to that hook comes later, it will be executed after the hook from `chemmacros`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewChemLatin\insitu{in-situ}}
\begin{document}
  \insitu
\end{document}
```

gives

> *in-situ*

Comment: I notified the package author https://github.com/cgnieder/chemmacros/issues/22