# How to use \xspace with chemmacros Latin phrases

Tags: chemmacros, xspace

I would like to add `\xspace` to the Latin phrases of the `chemmacros` package because I don't want to use `\` or `{}` at the end of commands without arguments.
However, when I try to define a new Latin phrase like `\NewChemLatin{\testtest}{testtest\xspace}`, the `\xspace` is ignored.
Also, I would like to avoid having to renew all the already defined Latin phrases or to add new helper commands like `\newcommand{\xinsitu}{\insitu\xspace}` or something like that.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros,xspace}
\NewChemLatin{\test}{test\xspace}
\newcommand{\xtest}{\test\xspace}
\begin{document}
    This is a \test within a sentence.
    And this is an end-of-sentence \test.

    Now, this is an x-\xtest within a sentence.
    And this is an end-of-sentence x-\xtest.
\end{document}
```

So, how can this be achieved?

Comment: That is one of the reasons why I never use xspace. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620.

Comment: Well, I am still learning. Thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem of having to redefine each Latin phrase one by one or having to use helper commands as in egregs answer.

Because

1. the `\NewChemLatin{constant}{phrase}` command actually pretty much just creates a constant with the value `phrase` which is wrapped in whatever is defined for the `nomenclature` modules `format` option (standard is `\emph`)

and

2. all predefined Latin phrases (`\insitu`, `\invacuo` and `\abinitio`) are only later defined in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook (see [Renewing Latin Phrases in chemmacros does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447242/renewing-latin-phrases-in-chemmacros-does-not-work/447270#447270))

the `\NewChemLatin`command can simply be overwritten via `\RenewDocumentCommand` to fit your needs. This way you can add `\xspace` or whatever you need. The only drawback (if it is any) I can think of is, that you will not be able to use the `format` option of the `nomenclature` module.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{xspace}

%to overwrite the \NewChemLatin command which is used for all Latin phrases
\RenewDocumentCommand{\NewChemLatin}{mm}{
    \newcommand*{#1}{\emph{#2}\xspace}
}

%new constants will be formatted the same ways a s the standard ones
\NewChemLatin{\test}{test}

\begin{document}
    Mid sentence \insitu   and at the end: \insitu.   \\
    Mid sentence \invacuo  and at the end: \invacuo.  \\
    Mid sentence \abinitio and at the end: \abinitio. \\
    Mid sentence \test     and at the end: \test.     \\
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

When you do `\NewChemLatin{\test}{test\xspace}` and call `\test`, the result is, essentially,

```
\emph{test\xspace}
```

so `\xspace` actually sees `}` and doesn't add the space.

You *might* do

```
\NewChemLatin{\innertest}{test}
\newcommand{\test}{\innertest\xspace}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros,xspace}

\NewChemLatin{\innertest}{test}
\newcommand{\test}{\innertest\xspace}

\begin{document}

This is a \test within a sentence.
And this is an end-of-sentence \test.

\end{document}
```

[image]

1. Don't use `\xspace`. Here is why: [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565)
2. Don't use `minimal`. Here is why: [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114)

Comment: So, there is no way to avoid that helper command (`\innertest`) and I will have to write one for all the already existing phrases I guess? That last part just read like a slap on my hands, so I edited the answer for future unenlightened folks that stumble upon this answer.

Comment: @basseur `chemmacros` used to have support for `xspace`, but it was dropped with version 5.